# Facebook Graph-Api, get all Posts

Tags: facebook-graph-api

We need a solution to get all Posts from a Page to my server/database for a news-page. 
I decided to use the graph-API, with "/page-id/feed" this works but with the API-Token I get the error:

"message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 10,
"fbtrace_id": "A+6CgNUppkS"

OK, so this means I have to review my APP.... but if I go to review, I have to add an element.... but which one. 
And if I choose an element e.g. "manage_pages" this review wants me to send a screencast? But how can I make a screencast from a serversided script????

My question is, wether there is an easier way to get all posts from a page to my database/server for posting them on my news?

THANKS!!!!!

Comment: Is this a page you manage, or just any arbitrary public page?

Comment: the page is managed by myself.

Comment: Then it is not a use case for PPCA to begin with. To get your necessary permissions reviewed, check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/server-to-server-apps